# unable to implement local svg image in react-native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I am uanble to implement png converted svg to my react-native application even after installing below libraries
"react-native-svg": "false12.1.0",
"react-native-svg-uri": "false1.2.3",

I am using latest react-native version and has followed all steps to implement provided by various forum on google still getting 'TypeError:json.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures'

Please help me with the steps to implement local svg image file in the application

Comment: Are you using typescript?  can you share some of the code that you think should be working but is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

png converted SVG Icon

```
const MY_ICON = `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="512.000000pt" height="512.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 512.000000 512.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.16, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2019
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,512.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M4830 4494 c-23 -10 -612 -592 -1718 -1697 l-1682 -1682 -553 552
c-382 383 -563 557 -589 568 -79 32 -181 12 -234 -47 -53 -58 -71 -160 -40
-231 8 -18 288 -305 662 -678 526 -524 656 -649 688 -659 59 -19 137 -7 188
28 24 17 829 817 1790 1779 1244 1244 1752 1759 1763 1785 33 81 12 190 -47
245 -54 51 -157 68 -228 37z"/>
</g>
</svg>
`;
```

Quick way to achieve is with the `SvgXml` component from [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg).

```
import {SvgXml} from 'react-native-svg';
```

```
<SvgXml xml={MY_ICON} width={50} height={50} fill={'black'} />
```

Comment: I don't want to get into xml and other things, simply want to import the svg file and use it